# Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure Strong name validation failed

Tags: c#, .net

I have a project using the `Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll`. This .dll was not available on my development machine by default, so I downloaded it with Nuget, version 1.0.0.0 (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure/) and added the reference to my project. Its set to Copy Local, and is copied properly to the /bin/ directory when I build the project. Strong Name is set to True by default and not changable through the properties window.

If I run the project on that machine, either debug or the compiled version, everything is fine. However, when I move the /bin/ folder contents to another machine and run it there, the program crashes with the following error:

```
 System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
'Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure, Version=`1.0.0.0. Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed
```

So I assume its not signed properly, and sure enough sn.exe tells me that:

```
.\Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.dll is a delay-signed or test-signed assembly
```

I tried reinstalling the package through Nuget, and manually, but all of the versions I can find return the same result.

Am I looking at the wrong problem, or is there a way to use this .dll without having to turn off Strong Name validation? Possibly another version of the .dll I havent found? A different .dll?

I have looked at other people having the same problem with different dlls, mostly `Microsoft.Web.Assembly`, and the "solutions" to those problems, but they are not ideal in this case. This project will eventually be deployed to multiple servers, and I'd like to avoid having part of the installation be disabling signing verification for this .dll and adding it to the GAC if possible. I'd much rather have a properly signed version of the .dll available and included in the folder with the build, I'm just lost on how to accomplish that.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Thanks!

Comment: Nope, I ended up submitting the issue on the Powershell git tracker (they own it), and they told me they wont sign it because "You should use the binary built into Windows". The problem is, it is not. No machine I checked has this binary, from server 2008 to win 10 enterprise. The only place you can grab it is from their nuget package... I ended up switching my target to `System.Management`, which was less than ideal because it does not offer anywhere near the functionality, but at least it actually exists on every version of windows despite being "deprecated"... at least for now.

Comment: @Drew forgot to ping you on it.